# How to get the data/id of the authenticated user?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm struggling with a problem concerning how my code should know which is the data of the authenticated user or how I could fetch that.

I've completed my my authentication flow, meaning I can successfully register and login with token. I'm still logged in with a refresh of the page, my token is still stored in the ionic/storage.

I think this should actually be enough to get the specific user data/permissions of the authenticated data of the user. But I don't know how to do that.

When I fetch any user from a list and watch his profile, I just can simply pass on his id. How can I get the id of the authenticated user by just clicking on the profile tab?

I'm not coming from another page from where I could take the id. I have also put my auth.service code, if that helps you in order to help me because of the token, but important are the two last snippets (I think so).

This is my code:

**auth.service.ts**

```
 private token = null;
  user = null;
  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);



  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private storage: Storage, private helper: JwtHelperService,
              private plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkToken();
    });
   }

   checkToken() {
       this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
           if (access) {
               this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(access);
               this.authenticationState.next(true);
           }
       });
   }

   apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/api/token/`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
        tap(res => {
            this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, res['access']);
            this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, username);
            this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']);
            console.log('my user: ', this.user);
            this.authenticationState.next(true);
        }),
        catchError(e => {
            this.showAlert('Oops smth went wrong!');
            throw new Error(e);
        }));
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
  // get a user's profile
  getUserDetails(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users/${id}/`);
  }
```

**profile.ts**

```
 information = null;
 id: number;


      ngOnInit() {
        // How to get just the authenticated api?
        this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
         this.id = validateId(params.get('id'));
     });

        function validateId(id: any): number {
           return parseInt(id);
    }

     // Get the information from the API
    this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.information = result;
     });
   }
```

Comment: I didn't the actual problem, Did you mean you unable to get another user by id after authentication successfully? 

I need to know the endpoint of getting user by id need authentication before using it, right!

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElSayed no not another user that works fine. But how to get only the authenticated user. So if I'm logged in as user1 how can I fetch the data of this auth. user1 ? The api endpoint is `http://1234/users/{id}/` with permission to update the user if its the authenticated user. So its not about to get any user(that works) but only to fetch the authenticated user. Like when looking at my own profile.

Comment: What is the return of this call?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElSayed response? => its just required an id. And then the data you get back is user info like username, email, etc. I want to display the data of the auth user in the own profile view.

Comment: I got it, When you open a profile of any user then try to open the current user profile, nothing changed, right?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElSayed not exactly. Let my simplify. e.g in Instagram when I click on my profile tab on the right. I get my user info. The same I want to do in my app.

Comment: Can you try my answer and tell me is it fix your problem?

Comment: use Localsotrage instead of Ionic Storage. It is more faster than Ionicsotrage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
You need to save your `user_id` into storage like this

```
this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.validateId(res['user_id']))
```

and In current user profile component get this `user_id` and pass it to `this.userService.getUserDetails` method like:

```
const currentUserId = this.storage.get(USER_ID); 

this.userService.getUserDetails(currentUserId).subscribe(user => { 
  console.log('user data', user);
});
```

**Old Answer**
Assuming the profile of any user is on the same route `(ex: profile/:userId)` including the current authenticated user

You just need to add this call inside subscription of `activatedRoute.paramMap`,

try

```
ngOnInit() {
  // How to get just the authenticated api?
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
    this.id = validateId(params.get('id'));

    // Get the information from the API
    this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.information = result;
    });
  });

  function validateId(id: any): number {
    return parseInt(id);
  }
}
```

Let me explain what happened, When you enter this component the `ngOnInit` hook is called and get user by id, and after you try to open the current authenticated user, only the callback of `activatedRoute.paramMap` subscription is called not all the `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: No sadly its not working. I get the error that id is not a number. But I also never get an id since Im not coming from another page like from user.page -> detail-user.page (where I can pass on an id like ` [routerLink]="['/', 'friendsdet', friend.id]"` Like with the example with Instagram. Im just logged in and I want to go to my profile tabs and see my data.

Comment: Or do I have to create a currentUserID in my authService?

Comment: To get the current user data we should have the current user id, Do you have current user Id?

Comment: Is user profile route URL different between the current user or any different user?

Comment: I want to store it like that. `export const USER_ID = 'user_id';` `this.storage.set(USER_ID, res[this.validateId('user_id')]);`

Comment: for users its just profile/:id for current user its just profile

Comment: Store it into the storage and when you enter `/profile` route get user id from the storage again and fire the request,

Comment: Ok ill try that. Somehow it say that my id in the storage is undefined. I first have to fix that :/

Comment: You need to do it like this 
`this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.validateId(res['user_id']))` not `this.storage.set(USER_ID, res[this.validateId('user_id')])`

Comment: Can you maybe show me how I would apply that.If my userid is stored in this const `export const USER_ID = 'user_id';`

Comment: If I understand correctly, After login you have user data into `res` object
this object has (`username`, `user_id`, ...etc) correct!
Can you confirm that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202226/discussion-between-abdelrhman-elsayed-and-colin-ragnarok).